# How to use multiple css files in one page in Express Handlebars

Tags: routes, express-handlebars

I have three pages Home, About and Create. I need to use 2 stylesheets for each page, one for the style and another for responsiveness. But it doesn't seem to work.

This is how one of my directory looks like

[image]

I've included the middleware as well
`app.use(express.static('public'));`

And in the `main.handlebars`, I've added this
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{style}}" />`

And this is one of my page's routing

```
app.get('/create', (req,res) => {
    res.render('create', {
        title: 'Blogger - Create',
        style: ['create.css', 'responsive.css'],
    });
});
```

However it works if I use a single css file

```
app.get('/create', (req,res) => {
    res.render('create', {
        title: 'Blogger - Create',
        style: 'create.css',
    });
});
```

Comment: When `style` is an array you would need an `{{#each}}` to loop through each item.